# Where has the AllenNLP Pruner gone?

Tags: allennlp

Allen NLP 0.9.0 (and maybe later) had a pruner module - intended to score and prune spans (https://docs.allennlp.org/v0.9.0/api/allennlp.modules.pruner.html). This seems to have gone missing, I cannot find it in the latest release, or the allennlp-models repo. Is it still part of the library - if not I have the original code so it's no big deal but if it was removed what was the reasoning?

Comment: I think this is long gone :/

Comment: That does seem to be the case @petew - it's odd but I feel like allennlp 0.9.0 is a totally different branch - many research projects I use still only support 0.9.0 - did they make significant breaking changes after this release?

Comment: There were definitely some breaking changes between the 0.9.0 and 1.0 releases. We try to adhere to semantic versioning though so breaking changes will only come with major releases.